# Using both Rspec 1.3.x and Rspec 2

Tags: rspec, rspec2

I remember a conflict in the past between the Rspec 1.x and Rspec 2.x binaries... since the binary has been renamed from 'spec' to 'rspec', can they now co-exist on the same machine without clobbering one another?

**Update:** Strangely, the two versions worked together fine under rvm on my Mac, but the spec binary complained about the version on the testing server.  Dchelimsky's [somewhat obscure solution](http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/2010/01/25/rspec-20-in-the-works/#comment-520) did the trick there.

Answer (score 0):

You can always alias or link in the bin a symbolic with another name, so after some long wind, yes.